# Angular2: Nested Observables in Guard

Tags: angular, typescript, router, observable, guard

I have a Guard protecting a certain route. In the `canActive` method I need to make two http requests, at which the second one is triggered based on the response of the first one. However, the second request is never made and I assume it is about the nested construct of returning Observables.

```
1 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
2          state: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<boolean>|boolean {
3  return this.provider.getA().map(
4    dataA => {
5      return this.provider.getB().map(
6        dataB => {
7          return (dataB.allowed);
8        }
9      );
     }
   );  
 }
```

Both getA() and getB() return the following:

```
getA() : Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(URL,payload).
                   map(response => response.json());
```

};

The code is simplified, but you may assume that getA() and getB() work properly. getA() is sent alright over the network when the Guard is called, getB() is never sent, though. The debugger exits silently in line 5.

One more thing, TypeScript shows a warning that probably tells me solution already, however, I'm too much a Noob with Observables in particular to know what to do with it:

```
Observable<Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable 
to type 'Observable<boolean>'
```

To make a guess, the construct of Observables never resolves, that's why there is no warning and I wait until the end of time. My naive notion was that, as long as any Observable will return a boolean (as done in line 7), the subscriber would know how to handle it.

I'm happy to read your hints. Off to bed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `switchMap` here:

```
return this.provider.getA().switchMap(
  dataA => {
    return this.provider.getB().map(
      dataB => {
        return (dataB.allowed);
      }
    );
  }
);
```

In your code, you are creating an Observable of Observables. `switchMap` flattens that structure and emits the emitted items of B through A.

Comment: That's it. I'll guess I sit down and go for the full Observables tutorial.

Comment: Go for it. It's incredible what you can do with them. Check out 'rx marbles'!

Answer (score 0):

## Update for solution shared by @j2l4e

Most of the RxJS operators are now pipeable, so without **pipe()** it will cause an error/warning.

**solution with pipe()**

```
  canActivate(): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Observable<Observable<boolean>> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
      .pipe(
        switchMap((dataA: any) => {
          console.log('dataA :: ', dataA);
          return this.httpClient
            .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .pipe(
              map((dataB: any) => {
                // add your logic here...
                console.log('data b', dataB);
                return false;
              })
            );
        })
      );
  }
```

For more info refer official docs:

1. https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators
2. https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/pipe
3. https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap